# Fast java byte[] manipulation

Tags: java, io, embedded, arrays, bytebuffer

I am trying to develop a Java application that will run on an embedded device. Since it is an embedded device it may be fairly slow. Speed is an important factor. After doing a little research on java.nio.ByteBuffer I see that it is quite slow and possibly I should have been avoiding it completely. Does anyone have any tips on how to handle a large byte[] easily? ByteBuffer is nice because it provides methods such as .getInt() or .getShort() as well as switching the ByteOrder endianness. Will I just have to live with the performance of a byte[]?

Comment: Focus on getting the functionality and then see if there are actually performance issues. Premature optimizations like this without actually seeing problems usually just cause more complexity and headaches.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to profile your application to make sure `ByteBuffer` is a bottleneck.  However, accessing native memory is generally faster than using jvm allocated memory...

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(8192);
```

There's a more expensive cost to allocating a native `ByteBuffer` over the heap allocated version though.  So, you generally want to limit how much you use them.  There are also platform differences, so you also probably want to profile for your specific purposes.